# How to load and save model with image-super-resolution repo?

Tags: python, tensorflow, github

I'm trying to use [this github repo](https://github.com/idealo/image-super-resolution) I'm able to run training with my own dataset but I can't fin how to load and save weights ?

This is my code:

```
from ISR.models import RRDN
from ISR.models import Discriminator
from ISR.models import Cut_VGG19
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint


lr_train_patch_size = 40
layers_to_extract = [5, 9]
scale = 2
hr_train_patch_size = lr_train_patch_size * scale

rrdn  = RRDN(arch_params={'C':4, 'D':3, 'G':64, 'G0':64, 'T':10, 'x':scale}, patch_size=lr_train_patch_size)

f_ext = Cut_VGG19(patch_size=hr_train_patch_size, layers_to_extract=layers_to_extract)
discr = Discriminator(patch_size=hr_train_patch_size, kernel_size=3)



from ISR.train import Trainer
loss_weights = {
  'generator': 0.0,
  'feature_extractor': 0.0833,
  'discriminator': 0.01
}
losses = {
  'generator': 'mae',
  'feature_extractor': 'mse',
  'discriminator': 'binary_crossentropy'
}

log_dirs = {'logs': './logs', 'weights': './weights'}

learning_rate = {'initial_value': 0.0004, 'decay_factor': 0.5, 'decay_frequency': 30}

flatness = {'min': 0.0, 'max': 0.15, 'increase': 0.01, 'increase_frequency': 5}

trainer = Trainer(
    generator=rrdn,
    discriminator=discr,
    feature_extractor=f_ext,
    lr_train_dir='lrtrain',
    hr_train_dir='hrtrain',
    lr_valid_dir='lrval',
    hr_valid_dir='hrval',
    loss_weights=loss_weights,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    flatness=flatness,
    dataname='image_dataset',
    log_dirs=log_dirs,
    weights_generator=None,
    weights_discriminator=None,
    n_validation=40,
)



trainer.train(
    epochs=80,
    steps_per_epoch=100,
    batch_size=16,
    monitored_metrics={'val_PSNR_Y': 'max'},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not have the answer, but after looking at this line:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    generator=rrdn,
    discriminator=discr,
    feature_extractor=f_ext,
    lr_train_dir='lrtrain',
    hr_train_dir='hrtrain',
    lr_valid_dir='lrval',
    hr_valid_dir='hrval',
    loss_weights=loss_weights,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    flatness=flatness,
    dataname='image_dataset',
    log_dirs=log_dirs,
    weights_generator=None,
    weights_discriminator=None,
    n_validation=40,
)
```

and reading some of the documentation, I think after:

```html
1- weights_generator and weights_discriminator are set to None in the trainer
2- you call Trainer.train() on trainer
2.5- weights_generator and weights_discriminator in the training process
3- TODO: save the updated weights_generator and weights_discriminator
```

I'm not entirely sure how to save the updated weights, but try:

```py
gener_weights = trainer.weights_generator
discrim_weights = trainer.weights_discriminator
#TODO: figure out the type of the above variables
#TRY: Maybe they would be some sort of a NumPy array or a tensor, idk!

#TODO: Then find a way to save it on your local machine
#TRY: Pickling them using the pickle library, for future usage.
```

My personal opinion is that you should probably find a way to save the entire model instead of the weights of the generator and the discriminator separately. I hope I helped even a little.

Comment: I found that I can do `rrdn.model.save_weights(file_path)` tosave the model and `rrdn.model.load_weights(file_path)` to load it